# Add every occurence of a key in every UITableViewCell's cell

Tags: ios, swift, function, uitableview, core-data

Every cell in my `UITableView` has an `amountValue` value stored in `CoreData`. My table view is a wallet so the final step is to add every `$` and display the grand total as the `wallet value`.

I am trying to iterate through every `amountValue` occurence in my `tableView` without success.

Here is my current situation:

```
func updateWalletValue() {

    // CryptosMO is the Managed Object with an `amountValue` attribute among others.

    var item : [CryptosMO] = []

    if CoreDataHandler.fetchObject() != nil {
        item = CoreDataHandler.fetchObject()!
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    for section in 0...self.tableView.numberOfSections {
        if (self.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: section) > 0) {
            for row in 0...self.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: section) {
                let total = item[row].amountValue! + item[row + 1].amountValue!

                print("TOTAL :", total)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For now I am getting a `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT` on the `App Delegate`.

**What can I do the fix the situation and make the calculation possible?**

EDIT: After further tests it is the access to `amountValue` that make the app crash..

Comment: Don't call data source methods `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRows(inSection:` yourself. Get the information from the data source array, actually the values which are returned in the data source methods. And instead of repeat loops use `map` and `reduce` to add up the values or fetch the data with `NSExpression`. To avoid the crash I recommend to declare `amountValue` non-optional (with a default value of 0.0) in the Core Data model and the `NSManagedObject` subclass

Comment: Why are you iterating the table at all?  YOU supplied the data to the table, why not just iterate directly over your data source?

Comment: @vadian It seems that I declared `amount` as a `string` in the `NSManagedObject subclass` instead of a double, but I see I can't declare it as a double anyway and have to use `NSNumber`. Also I see how I can declare it non-optional in the Core-Data model but I can't give it a default value anywhere in the pane. There is a `Validation` with `default` checked but the value is 0 and can't be changed.

Comment: @ghostatron You're right! I'm quite new to table view and thought this would be a good way to iterate at the correct `indexPath`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not very safe.  It's not that difficult to avoid forced unwrapping, and you should start by doing that.

for example:

```
  if CoreDataHandler.fetchObject() != nil {
        item = CoreDataHandler.fetchObject()!
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Aren't you throwing away the results of your initial fetchObject() call?
This could be rewritten as:

```
  if let nextItem = CoreDataHandler.fetchObject()  {
        item.append(nextItem)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

I'm assuming that item is your data source. [otherwise the call to reload your table view makes no sense]

The next block of code you provide can be refactored to be more safe as well. Verify you have an amountValue before doing any math on it.

Finally, this code is presumably not in your AppDelegate.swift file? Do you call this code from the app delegate?

You need to break this down into manageable chunks - I think you have more than one question here.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply apply **reduce** higher order method on item:

```
let total = item.reduce(Double(0.0)) { (result, nextItem) -> Double in
    return result + (nextItem.amountValue!)
}
```